# Encrypting Password Like Forms Authentication in .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, hash, passwords, forms-authentication

I have an old app that runs a read only membership provider. I am tasked with creating an admin page to help with adding/changing/deleting users from this app. The membership provider uses `FormsAuthentication`, which I cannot use because my admin app is in .net Core. I'm trying to reverse-engineer the way they encrypt using `FormsAuthentication` and I have this so far:

They use:

`FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "sha1").ToLower();`

I've reverse-engineered it to:

(string pwd is passed in)

```
HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new HMASHA1();
var step1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);
var step2 = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(step1);
var step3 = BinaryToHex(step2);
```

And step3 comes out to something like this "AD626B9D42073B299ECFC664CCB7A8B01F3AF726", which looks like what the passwords look like in the XML user file for the old app.

I'm just curious if I use this method of hashing (which works in .net core), will the hashed passwords be able to be "validated" by `FormsAuthentication`?

My tests so far don't seem to be working. Any ideas? Am I doing it wrong?

EDIT: it is not HMASHA1, it's SHA1Cng - which I can't use because it is in System.Core in the .net framework 4.something... what can I use to do this in .net core?

Comment: try `var newPassword=_userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user,newpass);`. if the default hasher doesn't work for you, you can also refer the [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c95ee2b051814b787b07f55ff224d03d550aafeb/src/Identity/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L94)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this works:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
var step1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);
var step2 = sha1.ComputeHash(step1);
var step3 = BinaryToHex(step2);
```

`BinaryToHex` and it's associated functions are copied from `System.Web.Security.Cryptography.CryptoUtil`

Would still like to be able to do this in reverse and decrypt passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different take, legacy hashed passwords in database

```
string incoming = inCrypt(inputPassword);
incoming=Regex.Replace(incoming, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "");


  public string inCrypt(string pwd)
        {
            var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            var step1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);
            var step2 = sha1.ComputeHash(step1);
            var step3 = BitConverter.ToString(step2);
            return step3.ToString();
        }
```

it worked, and the hashed passwords can be compared as strings.